# Error with JSONObject() - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to do a login view with Volley Library. 
It seems that "jsonobj" is always empty.

```
    val jsonobj = JSONObject()

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener {

        jsonobj.put("mail", mailTxt.text)
        jsonobj.put("pass", passTxt.text)

        val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
        val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonobj,
                Response.Listener{
                    response ->
                    toast(response["error"].toString())

               }, Response.ErrorListener {
               toast("Error")
           })
        que.add(req)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: It's not a syntactic error. It seems that jsonobj.put("mail", mailTxt.text) doesn't work fine, cause the response["error"] is always "No params"

Comment: have you tried a debugger instead of a toast? Such a message could easily have another source.

Comment: No but I'm pretty sure that nothing change